# Do unlimited use/season tickets for the Eurostar exist from Lille?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, eurostar, lille

When I look on the main [Eurostar website](http://www.eurostar.com/) about tickets, it only mentions specific-train tickets (of varying levels of flexibility), as a single or a return. I can't see anything there about any sort of unlimited use / season ticket type options.

However, a couple of nights ago I was chatting with some people in a bar in Lille, and they seemed to think that it was possible to buy a special ticket (aimed at commuters) for unlimited travel on the Eurostar starting in Lille. They were all sure that you could get such a ticket between Lille and Brussels, and fairly sure that there was a Lille to London one too.

Try as I might though, I can't find anything about these tickets by googling. Do they exist? Or were the locals describing "something that really ought to exist, but sadly doesn't"?

Comment: I very much doubt it, especially considering their [loyalty programmes](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/loyalty-programmes) are very reminiscent of airlines, which of course don't generally have season tickets.

Comment: I believe you can get a season ticket for travel by TGV, which is similar to the Eurostar, so the model isn't completely unknown

Comment: Loyalty programmes and seasonal tickets are not mutually exclusive.  For example, Swedish railway company SJ has both.

Comment: @Gagravarr drifting OT a bit, but how do the TGV seasons work with mandatory seat reservations?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what your question is, if you want to commute on Lille-Bruxelles or if you want to commute on the Eurostar.

For Eurostar, most likely I would say this is not the case. On the [SNCF page for commuters](http://www.sncf.com/en/reductions/daily-commute), while there is a link to actual commuter pages for other trains like TGVs and Thalys, there is no such thing for Eurostar, just a link to the frequent traveller program.

As for Thalys, they have frequent traveler passes (called ThePass), with [discounts up to 50% offon all your trips](https://www.thalys.com/fr/en/offers-and-fares/thepass) on Lille-Brussels with possible connections anywhere in Belgium.

Finally, for TGVs in France, there is an offer (Frequence or Forfait) and you can [simulate the price](https://monforfaitannuel.voyages-sncf.com/mnf/preadhesion) of such a pass. Unfortunately, there is no offer for Lille-Bruxelles nor for Lille-London. To answer @AakashM comment, TGV Forfait pass that offers unlimited rides on TGVs requires an extra fee for every seat reservation (1.5 euro per trip).

On [some help page](http://blog.voyages-sncf.com/lille-bruxelles), there is a suggestion to go to a station in Lille to know more about Lille-Bruxelles commutes. I would recommmend to do so, because there are probably quite a lot of people interested in such an offer, the train sales agents probably are used to it.

Comment: I left Lille last night, so it'd have to wait for another trip to ask in the station. Perhaps someone else will go there first? :)

Comment: At least one detail in this answer is out of date: [Thalys started serving Lille April 2014](https://www.thalys.com/nl/en/destinations/lille).

Comment: @gerrit Thanks for the notice, I updated the post